# Blaze Persistent CTE union subqueries in combination of queryDSL lead to syntax errors

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, blaze-persistence

I run in to a syntax problem where a union cannot be inside a union-all block when I attempt to use blaze persistence with queryDsl integration.

I am trying to union the result of two tables into one. Here is my original code:

```java
blazeJPAQueryFactory
                .select(
                        QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.id,
                        QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.createTime,
                        QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.userId,
                        QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.actionId
                )
                .from(
                        JPQLNextExpressions.select(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte)
                                .union(
                                        JPQLNextExpressions.select(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte)
                                                .from(QTopicCommentLikeRecordEntity.topicCommentLikeRecordEntity)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.id, QTopicCommentLikeRecordEntity.topicCommentLikeRecordEntity.id)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.userId, QTopicCommentLikeRecordEntity.topicCommentLikeRecordEntity.userId)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.createTime, QTopicCommentLikeRecordEntity.topicCommentLikeRecordEntity.createTime)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.actionId, QTopicCommentLikeRecordEntity.topicCommentLikeRecordEntity.commentId),
                                        JPQLNextExpressions.select(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte)
                                                .from(QTopicTitleLikeRecordEntity.topicTitleLikeRecordEntity)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.id, QTopicTitleLikeRecordEntity.topicTitleLikeRecordEntity.id)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.userId, QTopicTitleLikeRecordEntity.topicTitleLikeRecordEntity.userId)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.createTime, QTopicTitleLikeRecordEntity.topicTitleLikeRecordEntity.createTime)
                                                .bind(QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte.actionId, QTopicTitleLikeRecordEntity.topicTitleLikeRecordEntity.titleId)

                                )
                        ,
                        QLikeRecordCte.likeRecordCte
                ).fetch()
```

run this code and hibernate produces the following sql:

```sql
select
    likerecord0_.id as id1_0_,
    likerecord0_.action_id as action_i2_0_,
    likerecord0_.create_time as create_t3_0_,
    likerecord0_.user_id as user_id4_0_
from
    (
    select
        null id,
        null user_id,
        null create_time,
        null action_id
    from
        dual
    where
        1 = 0
union all (
    select
        topiccomme0_.id as col_0_0_,
        topiccomme0_.user_id as col_1_0_,
        topiccomme0_.create_time as col_2_0_,
        topiccomme0_.comment_id as col_3_0_
    from
        t_topic_comment_like_record topiccomme0_
    where
        ( topiccomme0_.del_flag = 0)
union
    select
        topictitle0_.id as col_0_0_,
        topictitle0_.user_id as col_1_0_,
        topictitle0_.create_time as col_2_0_,
        topictitle0_.title_id as col_3_0_
    from
        t_topic_title_like_record topictitle0_
    where
        ( topictitle0_.del_flag = 0))) likerecord0_
```

(you can ignore the `del_flag = 0` part as it does not influence the result)

since there is a union inside the union-all block, I get a sql error `heck the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union`

well the produced sql is at least conceptually clear and it would work if I just remove the whole 'select from dual and union all' part. I don't know why blaze have to wrap it with an union-all though.

Anyway I want the generated hibernate sql to be like this or at least close to the form of this:

```sql
select
    like_record.id,
    like_record.create_time,
    like_record.user_id,
    like_record.action_id
from (
    select
        t1.id as id,
        t1.user_id as user_id,
        t1.create_time as create_time,
        t1.comment_id as action_id
    from
        t_topic_comment_like_record t1
union
    select
        t2.id as id,
        t2.user_id as user_id,
        t2.create_time as create_time,
        t2.title_id as action_id
    from
        t_topic_title_like_record t2
) like_record
```

Please anyone tell me why the error occur and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: to be more precise, the syntax error is related to the nested union in the union-all. It seems my version of Mysql does not support nested unions. If I simply remove the parenthesis and tweak the select part a bit, the sql will work functionally.